# Accessing Variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have the following code:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } 
    else { 
        alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser');
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    alert(position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude);
    var Loc = position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

I need to be able to access the Loc variable outside of the function or through the GetLocation Function. As i need to bind it into a grid that I am creating for storing clock on and off to work information for offsite employees.

Here is the code that uses the variable Loc

```
getLocation();                      
                    var rowId=timesheetGrid.uid();
                    var pos = timesheetGrid.getRowsNum();
                    timesheetGrid.addRow(rowId,["","","","<?php echo $ActiveWeek; ?>","","","","","","","","","","",Loc],0); //adds a new row with pre filled data
                    timesheetGrid.selectCell(rowId,0,false,true,true); // Focus on the new row
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not just `return` that value? You set it, but don't do anything with it, which is pointless.

Comment: Where are you invoking this method from?

Comment: Declare it outside the scope of the function, assign the value from inside. Or return it from the function: `function showPosition(position){ ...; return Loc}`. BTW, variables starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors.

Comment: How is PHP relevant to this? Why did you add the PHP tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() is working in the asynchronous mode, and the function showPosition(position) is the callback function used to catch position. So you need to put all your code related to position in this callback function. For example, you can do like this:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(whenWeGetPosition);
    } 
    else { 
        alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser');
    }
}
function whenWeGetPosition(position) {
    // your code to use position
    var rowId=timesheetGrid.uid();
    var pos = timesheetGrid.getRowsNum();
    timesheetGrid.addRow(rowId,["","","","<?php echo $ActiveWeek; ?>","","","","","","","","","","",Loc],0); //adds a new row with pre filled data
    timesheetGrid.selectCell(rowId,0,false,true,true); // Focus on the new row  
}

getLocation();
```

Answer (score 0):

that can be achieved in two ways

- declare Loc outside of function

  ```
  var Loc = '';
  function showPosition(position) {
      alert(position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude);
      Loc = position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude;
  }
  ```
- or, just remove 'var' in Loc. it's now declared as global ( http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp )

  ```
  function showPosition(position) {
      alert(position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude);
      Loc = position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Loc = position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude;

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } 
    else { 
        alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser');
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    alert(position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude);

}

Make it global by moving it outside the function.
```

Comment: How would i then display it inside the second part of the code?
This Line of code should look something like this when the user clicks the add row button

timesheetGrid.addRow
(rowId,["","","","2016-03-09","","","","","","","","","","","Latitude Longitude"],0);

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, I am thinking you would then have to parse it.